# How to view animated GIFs in Android?

Tags: images

Is there a way to view animated GIFs on an Android device?  I searched the Market without success.

Comment: I would suggest trying to open them with the browser application using a file manager. Install a file manager that lets you choose "Run with..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Google [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=android+animated+gif) shows me a lot of people have this question...looks like it's still an issue.

Although one post [here](http://androidforums.com/g1-support/5781-animated-gifs.html) says [Image Viewer (with animation)](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-ideal-imageviewer-EzCz.aspx) v1.0 from Androlib.com helped (I have not tried it).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to buy something, especially since my phone is caught in a sign in loop with my gmail account... http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=3338af2b5afcbe7a&hl=en

Comment: Sign in loop sounds like a very good question of its own...

Comment: You're right.  It would have been, but I managed to fix it.  What's the etiquette for answering your own question?

Comment: Feel free to just ask then answer.

Answer (score 3):

I use [QuickPic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder) and it has a rating of 4.7.

Answer (score 2):

The Android browser will, but the image would have to be online somewhere. There's no way that I've found to open a local file in the browser. I *suppose* you could create an HTML file with the image and view it that way, but it seems a lot of hassle for little reward.

Comment: Animated gif's don't work in the browser of Android 2.0.  I guess I should have been more specific about what version I was using.

Comment: Well, there are alternative browsers you might try. I'm not currently using any of them, so I can't speak to how they handle animated GIFs.

Answer (score 1):

Navigating to the folder the gif file(s) are in with another browser besides the stock Android browser works for me.

E.G.: if your gifs are in the Downloads folder, Open Firefox, go to address bar, type in: `/storage/emulated/0/Download` (it may auto-complete for you). You should get a basic `Index of: ...` page from which you can click on the name of the gif.

Tested with [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) 21.0 and [Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) 27.0.1453.90 on a Nexus 4.
Both browsers accepted `/storage/emulated/0/Downloads`, but Chrome gave an Access Denied error on the shorter path `/storage/emulated/0`.

I recommend making a bookmark of the page, for easier access in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can view them in Firefox by typing in the gif folders destination.

`file:///mnt/sdcard/(name of gif folder)/`

It'll bring up the items in that folder as a list. Bookmark the page and store all your gifs in that folder. Firefox is the fastest gif player (that I know of).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop). It provides a feature called ES Image Viewer which can load any GIF image, including animated GIFs.

Where to find it:

[image: ES Image Browser]

"ES Image Browser" is the only one in the above list that plays animated GIFs (I also have jrummy's Root Browser installed).

Comment: it can show any .gif image you want. Vote up my answer if that helped

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [Animated Gif Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.wildcard.animatedgif.player)?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the location where the gif files are in Astro and open using Astro File manager.
Tried on Jelly Beans.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and couldnt find a quick fix in google. Played around and found that Andriod compresses images when sending MMS, so it breaks the GIF. But, if your GIF is under about 1MB, it will send. Iphone will auto play, andriod you have to click. the biggest one i tested was 666KB.

Your welcome internet

Answer (score -1):

The only app I've got that is able to run .gif files is [Fast Image Viewer Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tdfsoftware.fivfree).